# How to filter a Parquet file by datetime column while reading with Dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I would like to filter a Parquet file while reading it with Dask, but I do not manage to get it right and keep getting the same error.

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'
```

My current approach is:

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet(path="s3://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FOLDER/PREFIX]/*",
                      columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'DATE_COL'],
                      filters=[[('DATE_COL', '>=', '2020-05-01'), ('DATE_COL', '<', '2020-06-01')]],
                      engine="pyarrow-dataset")
```

'DATE_COL' has dtype `datetime64[ns]` and some NaT values. The other columns have dtype `object`.

Does anyone know how to do this? Perhaps I need to supply the dtype parameter, if that is the case how do I tell the `read_parquet()` method that 'DATE_COL' is a datetime column?

**UPDATE**

If I try the following:

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet(path="s3://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FOLDER/PREFIX]/*",
                      columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'DATE_COL'],
                      filters=[[('DATE_COL', '>=', pd.Timestamp('2020-05-01')), ('DATE_COL', '<', pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01'))]],
                      engine="pyarrow-dataset")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware timestamps
```

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware timestamps

This suggests that you should specify a timezone for your timestamp, e.g. `pd.Timestamp('2020-05-01', tz="US/Eastern")`.

Comment: more likely "UTC"

Comment: Thanks, I somehow guess this is financial data, which tends to be on Eastern time...

Comment: That's not the point: parquet stores everything in UTC. It may depend on what framework wrote the data, as to whether any timezone metadata is present at all.

Comment: Both Parquet and Arrow (which is helping out with the filtering here) store all Timestamps in UTC.  That being said, you may still want to use something other than UTC when defining your literals.  The UTC representation of that literal will be used under the hood for comparisons.  For example, if these are transactions and you wanted all transactions that occurred on May, in New York, you would specify Eastern time.  Now, if you wanted all transactions that occurred on May, in the time zone that recorded the data, then you're out of luck.  There is not enough information here for that.

Comment: Thanks. I guess a way out of that would be to specify wider bands and do some further filtering once the data is in memory...

Comment: I notice you are using engine='pyarrow-dataset'. I think it must be 'auto', 'pyarrow' or 'fastparquet'. Changing that, however, will not help. I've had the same problem as you when attempting to filter on timestamps using dask to read parquet file sets. The odd thing is that Pandas (with engine='pyarrow') and pyarrow can both read the filtered parquet data without any problem, both from S3 and my local drive. My attempts with dask, however, fail in ways you have described in either case, except I don't get the timezone error.